# Magento, Cannot send headers, curl_exec

Tags: php, magento, curl

I have some trouble with a cannot send headers, headers already sent. I done some, no a lot of research on google, with this issue, but without success.

**Cannot send headers; headers already sent in /var/www/webpage.com/public_html/app/code/local/Sikkerthjem/Aktivering/controllers/IndexController.php, line 111**

Code:

```
$ch = curl_init();
$str_cookie = 'APIKEY=' . $this->api_key . '; path=/';

$json_encode = urldecode(http_build_query($fields));

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $json_encode);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, $str_cookie );

curl_exec($ch); <-- This is line 111

curl_close($ch);
```

I have checked for whitespaces.
I really hope, one of you have a answer to this problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You output something to the browser before! just check your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happened because your output is sent before you have sent the header from your php. During executing the curl, its by default printing the html response. To stop this you can use this curl header:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
```

This is basically returning the html resposne from the `curl_exec` operation. Which you can catch like this way:

```
$result = curl_exec($ch);
```

Comment: Yeah, I have tried that.. but didnt have any effect. The problem only seems to be with the clients online environment, I dont get any errors on my local wamp. I have checked that all the necessary extentions is installed, and they are. 

Its proberly a stupid mistake somewhere, one of those DOOOOH-moments ;-)

Comment: Well, the answer is correct for the question. Just if anybody else should stop by ;-)

Comment: I stopped by and it worked for me as I did no have any whitespace/header before this, yet just calling curl_exec() will indeed output a header when not using this CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER fix